# Microsoft Operations Management Suite - "AD Replication Status" "No Data Found"

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, replication, azure-active-directory

I recently started using OMS. I have installed the MMA agent on both on-prem DC's. There is no on-prem SCCM.

On the console is says to AD Replication Status | "No Data Found" | Click here to troubleshoot. When it pushes through to the next page I get status on the 2 servers that have MMA installed Both indicate a message of "Computer meets all requirements to be a valid assessment target."

I don't see or have any data for AD Replication status.

I have tried various search sites but it seems that the problem may be so new I can't find any information specifically on this problem. 
I've attached a couple of images for clarification.

[results saying valid assess target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG1hR.jpg)